# is serialization in NestJs the same as DTO pattern?

Tags: nestjs

currently I'm learning NestJs. In the docu I have read about serialization. With this, we can transform our objects. I also know the DTO pattern.

Is serialization a kinf of implementation of the DTO pattern? I mean, with it I can exclude, expose, etc. fields.

I'm a bit confused about this topic.

I have a Java background and there I had my DTO classes and a mapper.

What are the options in NestJs to implement the DTO pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You can learn more about DTOs in NestJS in the [Validation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation) page of the documentation ; and more about serialization in the [Serialization](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization) page.

As stated in the documentation (emphasis added):

> Serialization is a process that happens **before objects are returned** in a network response.

While:

> The ValidationPipe provides a convenient approach to enforce validation rules **for all incoming client payloads**, where the specific rules are declared with simple annotations in local class/DTO declarations in each module.

I also recommend you check the [CRUD generator recipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/crud-generator) which will generate DTOs files automatically (although not their content ;))